# Add target and rel with php

Tags: php, target, rel

Imagine you have this markup:

Original code:

```
<p class="Add">
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
</p>
```

Desired code:

```
<p class="Add">
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noFollow noReferrer" class="l">Google</a>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noFollow noReferrer" class="l">Google</a>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noFollow noReferrer" class="l">Google</a>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noFollow noReferrer" class="l">Google</a>
</p>
```

Targeting the "p" with the class "Add", how can I with php add:

- The "target" property to all nested elements
- The "rel" property to all nested elements
- The class "l" to all nested elements

**I need to dynamically change the html structure**, the original links are constructed by a module and I cannot change them before the original html is constructed. Before I was doing it with javascript but js is not an option because some users do not have js enabled in the browser.

My previous js code is:

```
$(".Add a").attr("target", "_blank");
$(".Add a").attr("rel", "noFollow noReferrer");
$(".Add a").addClass("l");
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to dynamically generate these links in PHP?  How did you create the originals?

Comment: Yes EatPeanutButter, I need to change them dynamically. Sorry I forgot to refr that. The original links are constructed by a module and I cannot change them before this html is constructed. Before I was doing it with javascript but js is not an option because some users no not have js enabled in the browser.

Comment: It woulds be great if you mention how you call the "module" which creates the links.

Comment: `str_replace()`

Comment: Louys Patrice Bessette it is a core module from the CMS. I do not call it manually pre se. Jared Farrish I will check that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? you can make this so that it only prints if a certain condition is met.

```
<p class="Add">
    <a href='https://google.com' <?php echo("target='_blank'") ?> <?php echo("rel='noFollow noReferrer'") ?> <?php echo("class='l'") ?>>Google</a>
    <a href='https://google.com' <?php echo("target='_blank'") ?> <?php echo("rel='noFollow noReferrer'") ?> <?php echo("class='l'") ?>>Google</a>
    <a href='https://google.com' <?php echo("target='_blank'") ?> <?php echo("rel='noFollow noReferrer'") ?> <?php echo("class='l'") ?>>Google</a>
    <a href='https://google.com' <?php echo("target='_blank'") ?> <?php echo("rel='noFollow noReferrer'") ?> <?php echo("class='l'") ?>>Google</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris but I need to change them dynamically. Sorry I forgot to refer that. The original links are constructed by a module and I cannot change them before this html is constructed. I edited my question to better explain it. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use Javascript to add in those attributes once the page has loaded? you can loop over this for example document.getElementsByClassName("add")[0].setAttribute("target", "_blank");